# Unable to create bean in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am getting this

Error creating the bean with name 'listsServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'listRepo'

every time I run my project, I get this error.I started playing with spring boot following this

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-couchbase

**ListRepository.java**

```
package com.test.example.repo;   
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository; 
import com.test.example.entity.Lists;

public interface ListsRepository extends CrudRepository<Lists,String>{
  }
```

**ListsService.java**

package com.test.example.service;
 import com.test.example.entity.Lists;

```
public interface ListsService { 
   void create(Lists list);     boolean
   checkListName(String listName, String userId); 
}
```

**ListsServiceImpl**

```
package com.test.example.service;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired; 
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.test.example.entity.Lists;
import com.test.example.repo.ListsRepository;

@Service 
public class ListsServiceImpl implements ListsService{

 @Autowired     
 private ListsRepository listRepo;

 @Override  
 public void create(Lists list) {       
         listRepo.save(list);   
 }

  @Override     
  public boolean checkListName(String listName, String userId) {        
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub        
     return false;  
    }
```

}

Comment: Everything is in different packages and Spring Boot will only scan things in the package the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class is in. It is also recommended to place this class in a top-level package i.e. in `com.test.example` and not in a sub-package of that. That way it will scan all the other packages and enable things like Spring Data Repositories.

Comment: package com.test.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.test")
public class ExploreApiApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(ExploreApiApplication.class, args);
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

add

> @ComponentScan("com.test.example")

in your main application class.

Comment: change ListsRepository reference from listRepo to listsRepository in ListsServiceImpl.java

Answer (score 0):

Just add `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation to your config class.

Comment: I have enabled it,I am using this @EnableCouchbaseRepositories(basePackages = { "com.test.example.repo" })